# Getting position from multiple characters in a string

Tags: ruby, string

I can only get the position of the first space `" "` but not the other three using `index`.

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
puts text.index(" ")
```

Is there any way to get the position of the other three spaces?
Should I use any other string method?

Edit:
I ended up solving it myself.

```
i = 0
while i < text.length do
    if text[i] == " "
        puts i
    end
    i += 1
end
```

I looped through the string until it found a space, and then it displayed the variable `i`, which in this case is equal to the positioning of the spaces in the string.